# Separate Reactive Add and Edit Form in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to `angular 2` and want to create some `reactive forms`. I was working in `Laravel` and there we had separate `add and edit forms`.

**I have seen unclear implementation on editing a form in Angular 2.**

Like these:

```
http://learnangular2.com/forms/

https://auth0.com/blog/angular2-series-forms-and-custom-validation/
```

I have some multiple questions about the forms:

**1. What is the best way to create reactive add and edit a form where we would have multiple fields including *selectors*, *checkbox*, *radio buttons* and other multiple fields??**

**2. What is the best way of querying the server from angular 2?**

**i.e. If i have multiple select box, how should i get the data from server to fill the selectbox before the page load completes??**

Hope i have explained the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. u need to use "FormBuilder" to ease the development of your reactive form.
   generally, u need to create form group and form control and bind/connect them     with ngModel or u can use the changeValues property to work with Observable.
   please take a look [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html)
2. u can use several methods:

   - u can use route resolver. means that when the before u enter specfic route u will execute some logic (read [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html#defining-resolvers))
   - u can use the ngOnInit Method and get all the info that u need via services. after that u can subscribe the Observable (if u use the http service), and build dynamic the form by the FormBuilder